# Block Direct Access to Dynamic PHP-Image

Tags: php, html, image, apache, .htaccess

I have a PHP page called `test.php` on which I link to a dynamic image called `image.php` as follows:

```
echo "<img src=\"image.php?ID=abc&X=123\" align=\"absmiddle\" style=\"margin:5px;\"><br>";
```

The image file takes `ID` and `X` as GET parameters, and uses them to `include` an existing static image from my server. A header is sent telling the server to interpret the file as a jpeg.

I want to prevent users from being able to pull the image by visiting `http://mydomain.com/image.php?ID=/abc&X=123`, all while allowing that image to be viewed in `test.php` and other pages on my server. How do I accomplish this?

So far, I've tried many sorts of `.htaccess` mods and rewrites, of which the closest in relevance to my concerns is [the one shown on this page](http://bit.ly/aLM8jQ). Nothing has worked; please help!

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input. While your answers set me in the right direction, the solution on this page is exactly what I needed: http://bit.ly/fN2RSN

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, because what your browser does to show the image is **direct access**.

There will be a lot of advices about analysing `HTTP_REFERER`, but it will be a bad decisions, since this header is optional and in several circumstances it can be cutted off by firewall, antivirus, proxy, etc.

Comment: @romanusfatuus: it doesn't solve the issues I described in my answer. Nothing interesting there. The best thing you can do is just to check (in .htaccess, of course, **not in php**) either referer exists and equal to current domain or doesn't exist at all. This is the good compromise I think.

Comment: Thanks so much! I’ll incorporate that measure.

Answer (score 0):

I) Use sessions:

test.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
//....
$_SESSION["allow_images"]="yes";
echo "<img src=\"image.php?ID=abc&X=123\" align=\"absmiddle\" style=\"margin:5px;\"><br>";
?>
```

image.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["allow_images"]) { 
  // render image
  unset($_SESSION["allow_images"]);
} else {
  // throw error/ show dummy image /etc
}
?>
```

II)  Second solution (not foolproof):

Inside image.php

```
$ref=$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; 
if($ref == "http://yoursite.com/path/test.php") {  
   // get image parameters and render image
} else {
   // throw error or maybe render a dummy image with just few bytes
};
```

Note that HTTP_REFERER can easily be spoofed.

---

Earlier Wrong solution:

Use variables in test.php

```
$allow_image="yes";
echo "<img src=\"image.php?ID=abc&X=123\" align=\"absmiddle\" style=\"margin:5px;\"><br>";
```

And test for isset($allow_images) in image.php before rendering. Would have worked only if image.php was included as romanusfatuus pointed out.

Comment: That would only work if I were to `include` the image into `test.php`, giving it access to the containing code. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, `image.php` cannot see or even determine the existence of `$allow_image_access` the way I wish to reference it.

Comment: Sorry, seems the variables work only if you "include" the file. But something along these lines should work.

Comment: True. HTTP_REFERER is another way, though that is not foolproof.

Comment: Unless a hacker hacks your server, the solution using SESSION variables is secure - they cannot be spoofed by a normal user. (see this discussion http://www.webhostingtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-290980.html).

Comment: @ JP19L SESSION variables are secure, but not practical for this solution

Comment: @Stanislav: Is there a better way? I planned to use something similar for my use also.

Comment: @ JP19L : As zerkms answered in the first post, there is no way.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this site has the solution spot-on: http://bit.ly/fN2RSN